# CS50P: Check50 is saying my code doesn't have an output but when I manually test it there is an output

Tags: python, cs50

I have a task with this [image]

I'm quite confused if I check my code automatically with check50 it says this.

```
:( coke terminates at 50 cents
    expected "Change Owed: 0...", not ""
```

[image]

But if I check it manually, it works

```
Amount Due:  50
Insert Coin: 25
Amount Due: 25
Amount Due:  50
Insert Coin: 25
Change Owed: 0
```

Here's my code

```py
total_inserted = 0
due = 50
result = 0

while due > 0:
    print("Amount Due: ", due)
    coins = int(input("Insert Coin: "))

    #this coke machine only accepts 5,10,25 cents this if else statement checks if u enter the needed coins
    if coins in [5,10,25]:
        total_inserted += coins

        #This one subtracts the Amount due base on the coins the user entered
        computation = due - total_inserted

        #This one prevents the result to become a negative number
        result = abs(computation)

        #dont mind this one, this is my fix on one of the recent issue i had on this task
        if result == 10:
            print("Change Owed: "+ str(result))
            break
        elif result == 0:
            print("Change Owed: "+ str(result))
            break
        else:
            print("Amount Due: "+ str(result))
    #This one will show up if u did not enter the required coins like 5,10,25
    else:
        print("Amount Due: "+ str(due))
        break
```

I hope you could help me with this like give suggestions or something. Your help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You say "dont mind this one", but that's EXACTLY the problem here.  The test case enters 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, but on the 4th 10, you're printing the wrong thing and exiting.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim Roberts said, you can't ignore the errors when the user inputs `10` five consecutive times. That's perfectly valid input and should work. Ignore at your peril!

This code has so many issues.

- You have a `while` loop on `due > 0`, then you never decrement the value of `due`. Instead you use breaks. This has other impacts.

  - `Amount Due:` is frequently printed twice. First the correct `Amount Due: ##` is printed, followed by this line: `Amount Due:  50`.
  - If you decrement `due` properly, you won't need variables
    `total_inserted, computation, and result`.
- You have an `else:` to catch invalid user input, then `break` out of the loop. So if the user inputs `17`, you exit the program.
- There is a logic error when the user inputs more than the amount due.
  Test this input sequence: `25,10,10,10` and see what you get. It should print `Change Owed: 5` and exit. That's not what happens.
- Don't use a special `if` statement for `result == 10`. This just creates more logic problems. For example, if the user inputs 5x 10, you never print `Change Owed: 0`.
- Finally, you have to be careful on output formatting. `check50` is
  very picky about number of spaces. (In other words, you can have the
  correct answer, and it will fail if you have too few or too many
  spaces.) Watch the demo carefully.

With these changes, you should be able to compress this program down from 31 lines to 14-15 lines (depending on comments and white space/blank lines). Simpler is better. :-)